# move object to opposite side of canvas when object reaches the edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a game where a block moves across the canvas using [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/game_intro.asp) I want the block to move back to the beginning when it touches the edge, how do I do this? I know very little javascript, I just started learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an if-statement and place it within the canvas refresh loop to move the object when it reaches 1200px (or another canvas width)

```
function updateGameArea() {
myGameArea.clear();

if(myGamePiece.x>1200)
myGamePiece.x=0;
myGamePiece.x += velocity;
if (velocity < 0) {velocity += 1}
myGamePiece.update();
}
```